# How to store fetched JSON object into global variable"?

Tags: javascript, html, json, http, fetch

I am trying to store a JSON object obtained by the 'fetch' function into a global variable however it seems to have asynchronous issues when running.

```
function getCustomerId(name) {
    var output;

    fetch("url" + name)
    .then(
        function(response) {
            if (response.status !== 200) {
                console.log("Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: " + response.status);
                return;
            }
            response.json().then(function(data) {
                console.log("CustomerId:" + data.id); //I have a column in my database called 'id'
                output = data.id;
            });
        }
    )

    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("Fetch Error :-S", err);
    });

    console.log(output);
}
```

The returned response right now is:

```
undefined
CustomerId:A1234B123C
```

Comment: Yes. the last console.log(output); need to be after you set the value. Otherwise console.log(output); will be executed before the data return from your call. Best way to take care of this, call a function when the result return and then run the code that depends upon the return data. But I am not sure of your usecase.

Comment: @MisterJojo yups thanks! I've been scouring for stack pages and the one you linked provided the missing parts.

Answer (score 1):

try to do it with async/await:

```js
async function getCustomerId(name) {
  var output;
  let response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
  if (response.status !== 200) {
    console.log("Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: " + response.status);
  } else {
    const data = await response.json()
      //console.log("CustomerId:" + data.id); 
      output = data.id;
      console.log(data.id)
  }
  console.log(output);
}

getCustomerId()
```

Comment: I just tried this and it doesn't work. The console.log(output) is still being ran before the response finishes.

Comment: Oh! I'll check it now, sorry...

Comment: I have found the solution and will post it. Thanks for the support!

Comment: I'm sorry I'm late,  not at all :)